# How to use SUM and COUNT in sql query

Tags: mysql

I want to add the total marks of different three table in my database and find the number of students whose marks is less than 80. So I did it this way:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM((totalmarks / 30) * 5) AS marks1 FROM marks) +
    (SELECT SUM((totalmarks / 25) * 5) AS marks2 FROM marks2) +
    (SELECT SUM((totalmarks / 15) * 5) AS marks3 FROM marks3) AS result
HAVING COUNT((result / 300) * 50) < 80
```

I am able to get the sum of the marks, but when I put `HAVING COUNT` condition, it shows nothing. Can someone tell me how to get the number of student using `COUNT`?

It shows error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'HAVING COUNT((result/300)*50)>80' at line 11 .

Appreciate if someone can help me with this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTu0O.png)

Comment: You should group your results by student. What is the field for the student ID in your tables?

Comment: add the table definition

Comment: Count counts the number of rows in your resultset, not the value of the result. select count(1 + 1 +20); gives 1 not 22

Comment: @trincot thanks, the field for student ID is stuID.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your results by student:

```
select studID, sum(result) * 5 as result
from (
    select studID, totalmarks / 30 as result from marks1
    union all
    select studID, totalmarks / 25 as result from marks2
    union all
    select studID, totalmarks / 15 as result from marks3
) as base
group by studID
having  ((result / 300) * 50) < 80
```

NB: it is a bit strange how you divide and multiply. For example, why not the equivalent:

```
having  result < 480
```

If the logic is that in `marks1` the highest possible score is 30, for `marks2` 25 and for `marks3` 15, and you want to give each of the three an equal weighting, then indeed you must divide each of the `totalmarks` as you do.

After the multiplication with five, this would mean the result can never be more than five.

So the `having` test is then quite superfluous: all results will be below 480.

So maybe you wanted to see who did not have the perfect score, for which the `having` clause should then be:

```
having result < 5
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer.

Comment: Sir,how if I only want the number of student using COUNT? I mean it will only show how many student get marks less than than 480 for instance, it show result=18

Comment: I noticed you removed the acceptance flag. Was there an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using your current query, it needs a reference table/container to assess the `HAVING` condition.. so, here's my suggested solution:

```
SELECT result
FROM (
    SELECT (
        SELECT SUM(( totalmarks/30 )*5) AS marks1
        FROM marks
    ) + ( 
        SELECT SUM(( totalmarks/25 )*5) AS marks2
        FROM marks2 
    ) + ( 
        SELECT SUM(( totalmarks/15 )*5) AS marks3
        FROM marks3 
    ) AS `result` 
) AS `derived`
HAVING COUNT((result / 300) * 50) < 80
```

Comment: @Lawrence I think you need to the question your structure for the tables being used, so that we.. people of SO can further help you